# IntelliJ-IDEA SVN Credentials Not Accepted

Tags: authentication, intellij-idea, svn, repository

I'm using IntelliJ Enterprise Edition and am having problems accessing any SVN repositories (I do not have TortoiseSVN installed locally).  A work colleague gave me their copy of the TortoiseSVN\bin directory which I copied to my local machine and I updated the Settings of IntelliJ to point to the svn.exe application at this location rather than use the embedded version (which was also giving me the same problem).

The problem occurs whenever I open IntelliJ and select "Check out from Version Control -> Subversion".  I have entered the URL of my company's repository (the URL is correct - I have confirmed via web browser) and when I click on the expand icon I get a prompt saying "Authentication Required" which prompts for a username and password.  I am entering the correct credentials here (my Windows login) but the prompt immediately reappears.  So I can't check out from the repository but I have no idea why.

Comment: Do you have "Enable interactive mode" turned on? Is it possible to share idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE and reproducing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was to do with my SVN account not being permissioned correctly (I had been assigned the wrong privileges by the administrator).